# Design help for static content with fixed keywords search framework

Tags: python

I am trying to work out a solution for detecting traceability between source code and documentation. The most important use case is that the user needs to see the a collection of source code tokens (sorted by relevance to the documentation) that can be traced back to the documentation. She is wont be bothered about the code format, but somehow needs to see an "identifier- documentation" mapping to get the idea of traceability.

I take the tokens from source code files - somehow split the concatenated identifiers (SimpleMAXAnalyzer becomes "simple max analyzer"), which then act as search terms on the documentation. Search frameworks are best for doing this specific task - drilling down documents to locate stuff using powerful information retrieval algorithms. Whoosh looked really great python search... with a number of analyzer and filters.

Though the problem is similar to search - it differs in that the user is not physically doing any search. So am I solving the problem the right way? Given that everything is static and needs to computed only once - am I using a wrong tool(a search framework) for the job?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understand your use case. The user sees the source code and has some ways of jumping from a token to the appropriate part or a listing of the possible parts of the documentation, right?

Then a search tool seems to be the right tool for the job, although you could precompile every possible search (there is only a limited number of identifiers in the source, so you can calculate all possible references to the docs in advance).

Or are there any "canonical" parts of the documentation for every identifier? Then maybe some kind of index would be a better choice.

Maybe you could clarify your use case a bit further.

Edit: Maybe an alphabetical index of the documentation could be a step to the solution. Then you can look up the pages/chapters/sections for every token of the source, where all or most of its components are mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Your understanding is absolutely correct - only thing being the user does not see the source code in the code format - she is just interested in seeing a collection of the identifiers presented with relevance to the documentation. For each identifier the "listing of the possible parts of the documentation" needs to be shown. Unfortunately there are no "canonical" parts of the documentation - establishing it is the goal. Hope this explains things a bit more ... Can you explain "precompile every possible search" part? seems interesting